# What is the detection song in the mission "Deja Vu" from Metal Gear Solid V: Ground Zeroes?

Tags: game-music-identification, metal-gear-solid-5-ground-zeroes

I'm curious (as I love the song) — what is the song that plays when you get detected by an enemy on the mission "Deja Vu" in *Metal Gear Solid V: Ground Zeroes*? I couldn't find it anywhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Metal Gear Solid 1 song [Encounter (Alert)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xWMpeBSxfnQ) was beautifully remade for Ground Zeroes Deja Vu mission.

You can find a YouTube link of the song here:

Comment: I personally find "Encounter" from Metal Gear Solid 1 better than the remake now that I've heard it. I do thank you for supplying the GZ remake.